# Why isn't there image upload support on the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, images

It's quite annoying when I need to add a screenshot of a bug on the mobile site. I first post my question and leave placeholders for the images. Then I have to go to the full site, tap edit, remove the placeholder text, upload the image in its place, then save.

Can we add this feature? iOS natively supports uploading images now since iOS 5. I don't know about Android, but I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: I use iOS 5 and I can still upload images (not to SO, but to other sites that support it), it shows a little pop-up that says "take photo" or "choose existing"

Comment: @Doorknob oh. My mistake. I thought image upload was added in iOS 6. I'll fix it

Comment: Android supports HTML file upload [since 2.2 (May 2010)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Froyo). Some more devices in [File Upload Support on Mobile](http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/).